# How to fetch the images from this "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos" web API , and display on web page in Angular10?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

1. I have this API "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos" where there is following 5 properties

   ```
   albumId: 1
       id: 1
   thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
    title: "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt"
      url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952"
   ```
2. Here I have URLs of Images as well as Thumbnails.
3. I want the Albums with their Album Id should be shown in the First Page(one.component).
4. On clicking on a particular album,I have to show the Thumbnails of the Images (two.component).
5. And on clicking on the thumbnail, I have to open the Image in a pop-up gallery.

*My Code*

**one.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">

 <h5>Album with similar AlbumId will display here but in different blocks</h5>
 
 <!-- display Album serialy respective to their albumId  -->
 <h3 *ngFor=" " (click)="thumbnailOnClick()" routerLink="/two">albumID</h3> 

</div>
```

**one.component.ts**

```js
    export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
      
     constructor(private helperService:HelpService) { };
    
      ngOnInit(){
     
       this.getAlbumData();  
    
      };
      
      apiAlbumData=[];//data from api is stored in it.
    
      getAlbumData(){
    
        this.helperService.getAlbums().subscribe(apiAlbumData=>{
    
          console.log(apiAlbumData);
    
          //looping through apiAlbumData in console
          for(let value of this.apiAlbumData){
    
            console.log(value);        
    
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

**helper.service**

```js
    export class HelpService {
    
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
      getAlbums():Observable<any>{
       
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
       
         return this.http.get(url);
       
        };
    };
```

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried till now.

Comment: @VimalPatel here is my code what I have did yet

Comment: what is the problem which you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use http.get in angular to fetch api. Create an empty array and reassign it when you already received the data. I used rxjs map here. I also created an interface to have a cleaner code based on the object you are going to receive, in your case those 5 properties/fields. In your HTML template, you can now loop through those array data and display the ID first in your one.component. Here's my sample code.

```
// This is my interface

interface IPhoto {
   albumId: number;
   id: number;
   title: string;
   url: string;
   thumbnailUrl: string;
}

// Property in my class. This is an array that I will reference when
// receiving the data from API
public postArray: IPhoto[];

// This is my function fetching the api
fetchApiPhotos() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    return this.http.get(apiUrl).pipe(
        map((responseData: IPhoto[]) => {
            // I now assign the value to my array
            return this.postArray = responseData;
        })
    );
}

// Here's the HTML template
// Loop through the array and display the id
// on click of a button have a function that emits the data to be received by
// component two.
<article>
   <div *ngFor="let photo of postArray">
       <h2>{{photo.id}}</h2>
       <button (click)="showPhotoDetails(photo)">Details</button>
   </div>
</article>

// Function when you click the button
// This will emit/dispatch the data and the second component can 
// then receive it.
showPhotoDetails(photo: IPhoto) {
    this.photoItemClicked.emit(photo);
}
```

Either you use angular emit or service using observables if you want other components to listen/subscribe whenever there is an update/change.

Comment: What is the issue right now? I can help you with this but I think you need to have a sample link like stackblitz or codepen so I can check the whole application since there are components that need to link with each other. Basically what my example is just a sample draft to somehow mimic the behavior that you want.